# Why won't Postgres start after stopping it?

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

Postgres was running just fine (I have created a database using `template0`). Then, I used:

```
$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data stop --mode=smart
```

to stop Postgres and it stopped without a fuss. Then, I used:

```
$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -l /var/log/postgres/serverlog start
server starting
```

and it *appeared* to start without a fuss... but then:

```
$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data status                              
pg_ctl: no server running
```

Just to be sure, a `ps aux | grep postgres` returns nothing.

Why would this happen?

Note: I'm logged in as `postgres` and `/usr/local/pgsql/data` dir is recursively owned by `postgres`, but worth noting is that the `postgres` is using `/etc/sh` vs `/etc/bash` since I was stupid and used `useradd` vs `adduser`. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.2 and running Postgres 9.2.4.

Comment: Did you check the Postgres server logs?

Comment: Ah :( `This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded your kernel's SHMMAX parameter`...

Comment: I have 2GB of RAM. Any idea what my shmmax should be set to? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/kernel-resources.html gives some examples, but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to make the 4096 * max pages == my total RAM...

Comment: Which OS is this? Postgres 9.1 ran out of the box on my CentOS VPS with 512MB RAM...

Comment: @JoelESalas - I had configured `shared_buffers` to `256MB` - `shmmax` was something smaller by default. I updated it to `384MB` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` to get Postgres working again (the actual segment size requested was something like `277MB`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a service dies immediately after launching with no warning, you'll have to refer to the service logs to see what's going on. Generally it's a fairly egregious crash.

Check the Postgres server logs to see what, if anything, the service is logging before it dies.